# Oracle SQL : date in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I need to select rows by date greather than today.
Table has column LAUNCH_DATE which is of type TIMESTAMP.

I am trying to execute query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE LAUNCH_DATE >= to_timestamp('12.02.2016 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

result is `no rows selected`

But table has data for today. Query:

```
SELECT LAUNCH_DATE FROM TABLE1;
```

gives result:

```
10.02.16 16:32:48,000000000
12.02.16 12:35:30,000000000
10.02.16 19:33:37,000000000
12.02.16 12:32:37,000000000
```

Expression `<=` is working but shows all dates even for today.

`TO_DATE` also shows no selected rows

CREATE_TABLE script is here

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEST1"."TABLE1" 
   (    "ROW_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CONFIGURATION_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "BRANCH" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "ENVIRONMENT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LAUNCH_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "LINK" VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE), 
    "CONFIGURATION_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "TABLE1" PRIMARY KEY ("ROW_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TEST1"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TEST1" ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "TEST1"."TABLE1"."LAUNCH_DATE" IS 'время начала действия';
```

Comment: Please show "CREATE TABLE" used to create table "LAUNCH_DATE".

Comment: what does `select to_char(launch_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from table1;` show? (Sounds daft, maybe, but I'd like to confirm that the four-digit year for the rows is 2016 and not 1916 or something else.)

Comment: it shows year with leading `00`:`10/02/0016 16:32:48`

Comment: @Filomat . . . That's not today's date anywhere in the world.

Comment: As suspected: duff data. Fix the data (and whatever it was that added the data in the first place!) and all should be well.

Comment: thx a lot. I got it.